# How to change a state variable in a smart contract with web3.js

Tags: web3js

I am new to solidity and web3.js.

I have a very simple solidity code deployed on the rinkeby like

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract sample {
 string public name;
 function set(string _name) public {
    name = _name;
 }

 function get() public view returns (string){
   return name;
 }
}
```

After spending hours, I could figure out  how to get the state variable 'name' using web3.js. But, I could not get how to change the variable with web3.js. Any help? Please. I am using web3.js 0.20.3. Thanks/

Comment: Which version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: And are you using MetaMask, Truffle or Geth?

Comment: I am using infura as my provider.

Comment: I am using Geth.

Comment: Follow the following blog for setup https://blog.amr-gawish.com/building-a-production-ready-ethereum-dapp-from-idea-to-final-product-first-section-the-3b9975a226c

Answer (score 8):

what line of code are you exactly struggling with in web3?

I've made your code work in web3 1.0.0 with the following lines:

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3("...")
const abi = ...
const address = "..."

const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
myContract.methods.set("Hello").send({from:"..."}, function(){
  myContract.methods.get().call((error, result) => {console.log(result)})
})
```

In web3 0.20.x, the code should look something like this:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3("...")
const abi = ...
const address = "..."

const myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi)
const contractInstance = myContract.at(address)
contractInstance.set("Hello").sendTransaction({from:"..."}, function(){
  contractInstance.get().call((error, result) => {console.log(result)})
})
```

I'm not familiar with 0.20.x, so I may have written it wrong.

By the way: as far as I know, if you set a variable public in solidity, it automatically creates a getter function for it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But it does not work. As far as I know, isn't this supposed to need my signature because it changes a data in blockchain?

Comment: That's correct. You should use a `truffle-hdwallet-provider` ([see this git repo])(https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) to do the signing for you

Comment: @Henk is right. I used Ganache, so I did not need to sign my transactions. An alternative would be to use `personal.unlockAccount()` Using MetaMask would also be an option.

Comment: Helpful answer. This should be accepted